# Catching errors in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am a beginner with MS Access and I am having some issues. I have created a query with 2 different dates (say x and y) and then a formula to calculate the days between these two dates - column C. I am now looking to only pull through results where the criteria of column c is greater than 30, however it is creating an error as some of the dates in x and y are missing at table level. Is there a way to catch this error before the query? For example, the Excel equivalent of iferror("-").

Comment: Please provide your code, along with error and your expected result

See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *DateDiff* and filter for *Not Null* to ignore those records:

```sql
Select * 
From YourTable
Where 
    DateDiff("d", [x], [y]) > 30 
    And 
    [x] Is Not Null And [y] Is Not Null
```

Should that still fail, use *Nz*:

```sql
Select * 
From YourTable
Where 
    DateDiff("d", Nz([x], Date()), Nz([y], Date())) > 30 
    And 
    [x] Is Not Null And [y] Is Not Null
```